# Using OpenSSH on Windows for enterprise use

Tags: windows, cygwin, openssh

Is OpenSSH for Windows (using Cygwin) is considered to be robust & stable for enterprise use?

Comment: Why not use a Windows-native version (like Putty)? Cygwin won't give you any extra security if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: I think that liorix wants to use OpenSSH as a server, not a client, m0skit0.

Comment: That's correct, I want to use OpenSSH as server. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [freeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/). It works fine. No Cygwin required.

> freeSSHd, like it's name says, is a free implementation of an SSH server. It provides strong encryption and authentication over insecure networks like Internet. Users can open remote console or even access their remote files thanks to buit-in SFTP server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why any other free ssh server solution will outperform a cygwin openssh server on Windows regarding stability. (The installation process may be a little tricky but this doesn't affect stability.)

The cygwin openssh is a direct port of the most used and probably most stable ssh server currently available. I for myself didn't experience any problems yet with all of my cygwin openssh installations on private as well as server machines.

So if you are looking for a free ssh server, why don't give openssh a try?

As for commercial solutions I can't give any recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH seems to be robust and stable because it's standard for every Linux-Machine. The big Problem under Windows is Windows itselve, not the used SSH-Server. freeSSHD is stopped to be developed, OpenSSH is gnu.